# Control to state operator

Tags: optimization, operator-theory, convex-optimization

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n $ open bounded with Lipschits boundary $\Gamma$. Consider solving
\begin{align} \label{mainprob}
    \min_{y,u} J(y,u):= \Vert y-y_{\text{d}} \Vert ^2_{L^2(Q)}+ \frac{\lambda}{2}  \Vert u \Vert ^2_{L^2(\Omega)},  \tag{$P_1$}
\end{align}
subject to, \begin{align}
 \partial_t y -\Delta y 
  &= 0 \quad \mbox{in } \quad Q:=\Omega \times (0,T), \notag \\
 \partial_\eta y 
  &= 0 \quad \mbox{on } \quad \Sigma:= \Gamma \times (0,T), \notag \\
 y(\cdot,0) 
  &= u \quad \mbox{in } \quad \Omega . \label{nonlinearproblem}  \tag{PDE}
\end{align}
such that $$u \in \{v \in L^2(\Omega): \quad a \leq v \leq b,\quad a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}.$$
Then, \eqref{mainprob} can be reduced to \begin{align} \label{mainprob1}
    \min_{u} J(u):= \Vert y_u-y_{\text{d}} \Vert ^2_{L^2(Q)}+ \frac{\lambda}{2}  \Vert u \Vert ^2_{L^2(\Omega)},  \tag{$P_2$}
\end{align}
such that $y_u$ solves \eqref{nonlinearproblem} with $y_u(0,\cdot )=u$.

It is known that the \eqref{nonlinearproblem} has a unique solution (in the weak sense) $y_w$ for any given initial condition $w$, i.e $y(0,\cdot)=w$ with $w \in L^2(\Omega)$. In particular, the solution $y_w \in L^2(0,T;H^1(\Omega))$ where
$$\mathcal{H}:=L^2(0,T;H^1(\Omega))=\{f:(0,T) \rightarrow H^1(\Omega)\}.$$

My question is that when we define an operator $S:L^2(\Omega) \rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ by $u \mapsto y_u$, where $y_u$ solves \eqref{nonlinearproblem} with initial condition $y(0,\cdot)=u$, then it is easy to see that this operator is continuous, however, I need to prove that it is linear?

$\mathbf{My\ attempt}$: Let $u,v \in L^2(\Omega)$ with $y_u,y_v, y_{u+v}$ be the unique soltion to  the \eqref{nonlinearproblem} with the desired initial condition as stated for each $u,v,u+v$. Then what I am trying to show is that \begin{align} \|y_{u+v}-(y_u+y_v)\|_{\mathcal{H}} =0 \end{align}
But I could not see how to show it. I note just that \begin{align} \|y_{u+v}-(y_u+y_v)\|_{L^2(\{0\}\times \Omega)}=0 \end{align}

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't get your comment at the very end, $y_{u+v} = u + v$ and $y_u + y_v = u + v$ on $\{0\} \times \Omega$. Why do you take the $L^2$ norm ?

Comment: You are right it should be the $H^1$ norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linearity directly follows from the uniqueness of the solution and the linearity of your equation. Let $y_{u+v}$ be the solution of your equation for the initial condition $y(\cdot, 0) = u+v$. But, by linearity of your PDE, $y_u + y_v$ clearly solve your system for this initial condition. Hence you must have $y_{u+v} = y_u + y_v$.

Comment: What is we have a semilinear PDE, example  \begin{align}
 \partial_t y -\Delta y 
  +y^2= 0 \quad \mbox{in } \quad Q:=\Omega \times (0,T)
\end{align}

Comment: In that case the linearity doesn't hold anymore.

Comment: By the way, is the reduced model $(P_1)$ a convex functional? If we assume that we have the semilinear PDE above.

Comment: Yes, I think so. You have a constrained minimization problem $\min_{(y, u) \in A} J(y, u)$, where $A$ is the set of $(y, u)$ satisfying your PDE. If I am not mistaken, the convexity only comes from the convexity of $J$. But I am not at all an expert, so I might be talking shit.